# Hello im search solution for make one discord message after mysql query

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord

Hello guys this is my first discord bot and the question is:

How to make one message after query?

query

```
SELECT * FROM ${table}_${message.guild.id}`;
```

```
rows.forEach(function(row) {message.channel.send(`Name: ${row.username} Request: ${row.amount} Date: ${row.date}`);
```

now bot answer like this

```
bot: Name: user1 Request: 20 Date: 2020-06-22 17:53:01
bot: Name: user2 Request: 20 Date: 2020-06-22 17:54:36
```

need in one message

```
bot:---------------------------------------------
Name: user1 Request: 20 Date: 2020-06-22 17:53:01 
Name: user2 Request: 20 Date: 2020-06-22 17:54:36
```

ps. Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var outgoing="";
rows.forEach(function(row) {outgoing+=(`Name: ${row.username} Request: ${row.amount} Date: ${row.date}\n`);
message.channel.send(outgoing);
```

Comment: yep, im do this after got more reputation :)